# Fix a container vertically in a horizontal layout done by Polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer, fixed

I'm having a layout with a kind of a filesystem tree on the left with expanding folders and files and a detail view on the right. The layout is done with Polymer and it is horizontally flexible and has a core-splitter inbetween the two containers.

My goal is have the detail view on the right to be fixed vertically, so that it is in the viewport no matter how far down I scroll in the left container with the tree.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's possible. Three key things

1. Set `fit` on your parent container so that the container will take up the entire viewport.
2. Set [`allowOverflow`](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-splitter/index.html#core-splitter.attributes.allowOverflow) on your `<core-splitter>`.
3. Style your left-hand panel with `overflow-y: auto`.

Here's a working example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer Demo: core-splitter</title>
    
    <style>
      #left {
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body fullbleed>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-splitter/core-splitter.html">
  
    <div layout horizontal fit>
      <div id="left">
        <ul>
          <li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <core-splitter direction="left" minSize="128px" allowOverflow></core-splitter>

      <div id="right">
        <h1>I'm right!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```